# Is it possible to say more about the Itô integral $\int_0^TB_t^2dB_t$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Using Itô's formula, we can show that $\int_0^TB_t^2dB_t=B_T^3/3-\int_0^TB_tdt$.

Is it possible to say anything more, maybe about the distribution of this integral? It is of course the last term I am unsure about, do we know how that term is distributed. Is it possible to write this integral another way?

Comment: To get the distribution of $$X_T=\int_0^TB_t^2dB_t=\frac{B_T^3}3-\int_0^TB_tdt$$ (note the correction of the typos in the RHS), note that $B_t=\frac{t}TB_T+W_t$ where $(W_t)$ is a Brownian bridge independent of $B_T$ with [known distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge). Thus, $X_T$ is the sum of the independent random variables $$Y_T=\frac{B_T^3}3-\frac{TB_T}2\qquad\text{and}\qquad Z_T=\int_0^TW_tdt$$ Note that $Z_T$ is centered normal with known variance. Furthermore, $Y_T$ is distributed like $T\sqrt{T}Y_1$ and the distribution of $Y_1$ can ...

Comment: ... be computed since $Y_1$ is an explicit function of the standard normal random variable $B_1$.